# Python Matplotlib barchart updating color interactively

Tags: python, matplotlib, dynamic, interactive

I am trying to understand interactive plots in matplotlib (in Jupyter Notebook).

Here is a piece of codes and I would like to know why this is not working.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

BarChart = ax.bar(df.index, df.mean(axis=1), color = 'black')

def on_click(event):
    for Bar in BarChart:
        Bar.set_color(color='red')

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

plt.show()
```

Could anybody explain me why this is not updating the color of bars into red and how to fix it?

When the for loop is used in a static case, i.e. without the on_click and mpl_connect function, it does update the bar colors in the original plot.

I was wondering if I need an expression to explicitly updating the plot.

Comment: I have already tried that but it does not make any difference. Actually, the easy fix is just drawing the barchart again in the on_click function. But I just want to understand why I cannot change the color of the existing barchart.

Comment: Try removing `color=` in `set_color`. So it will be `Bar.set_color('red')`

Comment: Oh!. That worked!!!!! Thank you so much. :D I wasted the whole day yesterday because of this..... I looked up the set_color but somehow I could not find the documentation explicitly on this function.. Is there a way for me to select your answer as the answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Bar` is a Rectangle patch, therefore you can use [`set_color`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_color) to change the color of the bars. However, it does not accept `color` as a keyword argument. From the docs, the argument you need to use is `c`

Therefore, you can either remove `color=`, or replace it with `c=`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

BarChart = ax.bar(df.index, df.mean(axis=1), color = 'black')

def on_click(event):
    for Bar in BarChart:
        Bar.set_color('red')
        # Bar.set_color(c='red')  # this also works

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

plt.show()
```